# Would the Electric Fields of simultaneously transmitted waves affect eachther

Tags: electromagnetism, wave, field

If there are 2 waves, with different frequencies, wouldn't the Electric fields add up and impact both waves regardless of the frequency difference?

I attached a picture of what I mean, when there are 2 waves in an EM field, why do they not interfere with one another? Wouldn't the Electric Field at least in "some" points add up and cause some changes to the other wave?

If they are not impacted, then what is the 'thing' that doesn't allow them to be impacted? Is it simply that Photons do not interact with eachother? But wouldn't there be "some" portions of other waves which can touch the curve of another wave and therefore seem to the antenna that the wave changed?

[image]

Comment: I would not characterize it as changing the wave. Superposition would definitely apply at any point in space where both waves are present. But neither wave will change the direction or amplitude or frequency of the other traveling wave.

Comment: Wait a minute. You just asked practically the same question a few days ago.

Comment: No, my previous question (s) were speaking of interference and superposition. I was now thinking of the added Electric Field itself, and wanted to know if that would be treated differently in Signal Processing.

Comment: It sounds the same, but from a Quantum perspective it's different. I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends whether you are transmitting them through a linear or a non-linear medium.

If you are using a linear medium, like vacuum, or air or glass at sufficiently low fields, then yes, the resulting electric field you can measure at any point would be the sum of the two component fields. If you analyse the frequencies present in the combined signal, you would have only the ones you started off with, in the relative powers and phases that you started of with, and no others.

If the signals are to be received by an antenna, then the linearity condition has to be applied here as well. If there's an amplifier in the downlead from the antenna, then that has to be working at low enough level to stay linear.

If any of those components become non-linear, *then* you will see harmonics of the signals, and signals at sums and differences of the frequencies of the signals and their harmonics. If you have a very strong signal received at an antenna for instance, it will interfere with the weak signal you're trying to receive, by driving the downlead amplifier into overload. Once overloaded, it's non-linear. This is called intermodulation distortion.

If the electric field of signals travelling through the air is so powerful that it causes the air to break down and plasma to form, then the signals will intermodulate, the air is no longer linear. This takes some substantial power though, rather more than is needed to upset a downlead amplifier.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. It's very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that 2 electric fields (should call EM wave, as there is no independent E field under Maxwell) are on the same propagation plane. The E fields in time domain will superimpose on one another, creating a resulting waveform of vastly different shape in power vs time profile.

However, if you analyze the 2 waveforms in the frequency domain, you still can resolve them to their frequency components.

Comment: Thanks. So although it would change the waveform, it won't impact the amplitute or frequency? Wouldn't some components of wave2 add up to the amplitude of wave1 or vice versa? And therefore, in digital signal processing, errors may occur?

Comment: You get a resultant and superimposed waveform when you see it in TIME DOMAIN ONLY, and you still will be able to resolve them into their frequency components in frequency domain. That is the ABC when professor start teaching Fourier.

Comment: But my question is, even though you can differentiation in frequency domain, would wave2 not impact 'physically' wave1 where they might superimpose partially, and therefore even in Signal Processing in Frequency Domain, they may get a 1 instead of a 0?

Comment: Assuming you have two carrier F0 and F1, where they superimpose on one another, creating some funny shape Fsum in time domain. If you perform a fourrier transform, you will get F0 and F1, never mind the shape of Fsum. You can then return to time domain and plot out the F0 and F1, which is the component of Fsum.